# How to control user installed apps?

Tags: applications, root-access, lineageos, redmi-1s

Device Pre-installed Apps(Camera, Calendar, file manager etc. ) have options for 'Force Stop' and 'Enable/Disable' app. And, for User installed apps(from PlayStore etc.) have only options 'Force Stop' and 'Uninstall'.

I have set some applications to `start from boot`. Mostly, user apps are set to start, while  I touch them only. But, some user apps start automatically, and consumes RAM. I will Force Stop/remove those apps from RAM. But, it starts again after few hours.

Is there any method to **disable** such apps rather than uninstalling those apps.

Device : Xiaomi Redmi 1S - Lineage OS 14.1(rooted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a rooted device, it is possible to disable/enable user apps using a terminal emulator.

To do so, open a terminal of your choice, enter

```
su
```

to acquire root privileges and then enter

```
pm disable <packagename>
```

Take care to replace `<packagename>` with the package name of the app you wish to disable (for example, if you wish to disable WhatsApp, your command will be `pm disable com.whatsapp`).

To revert the process and thus enable a disabled app, acquire root privileges and issue

```
pm enable <packagename>
```

Again, remember to replace `<packagename>` with the package name of the disabled app you wish to enable.

Comment: An Xposed module named [XInstaller](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.xinstaller) can make this procedure easier.

Comment: @iBug I'm aware, but why not to use LOS' integrated Terminal? Feel free to write an answer too, if you want to provide a GUI alternative.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Xposed Framework installed, you should try [XInstaller](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.xinstaller).

Install it and reboot. Then navigate to **Apps Info**. Tap on **Disable User Apps** to enable this option. Now you can go to **Settings** -> **Manage Apps** and tap on an app. You'll see a **Disable** option under the usual **Uninstall** one.

Thanks to [*Death Mask Salesman*](/users/152843), you can also use XInstaller's successor for Android 6.0+, [InstallerOpt](http://repo.xposed.info/module/net.fypm.installeropt). It provides similar function and is intended to replace XInstaller, which is faulty in Android 6.

Disclosure: I am *not* affiliated with XInstaller or its author. I am just a fan user of it.

Comment: +1: this is a neat solution for anyone who also cares for more control over Android's Package Installer.

Comment: By the way, you might be interested in the spiritual successor, [InstallerOpt](http://repo.xposed.info/module/net.fypm.installeropt).

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Lol... [I switched to OnePlus 5](/q/177246) and Xp Fw is no longer available.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Your comment about InstallerOpt is a valid answer. You can post it.

Comment: Since InstallerOpt is the successor of XInstaller, I think that it would be best suited as an addition to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to free more RAM, then this could be useful:

- Go to Settings > Memory
- The last menu entry says something like "apps that start on boot"
- Click on each app that you don't want to run in background and disable the "start on boot" and "run in background" permissions

I've tested this on the latest version of Lineage OS (based on Android 7.1).